# Как начать перебор std::list с N-го элемента?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, list, перебор

Есть два алгоритма перебора листа:

```
for (auto iter = numbers.begin(); iter != numbers.end(); iter++){
        std::cout << *iter << "\t";
    }
```

И

```
for (int n : numbers) std::cout << n << "\t";
```

Оба этих алгоритма перечисляют элементы с 1го по последний.

А если нужно перечислить с Nго по последний?

Есть возможность в данном примере использовать нечто типа

```
size_t pos = 0;
for (auto iter = numbers.begin(); iter != numbers.end(); iter++){
       if (pos++ > N) std::cout << *iter << "\t";
}
```

Здесь я считал элементы с нуля.

Однако данный метод я нахожу костыльным, т.к.:

- Мы перебираем все элементы
- Доп. действия сравнения, а это время
- Такой код перестает быть легко читабельным

Есть ли более правильное решение данного вопроса?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Функция `std::next`, примененная к итератору, позволит вам найти любой элемент контейнера.

```
for (auto iter = std::next(numbers.begin(), n); iter != numbers.end(); ++iter)
```

Однако применение функции `std::next` (как и функции `std::advance`) с большим и/или неконстантным вторым параметром является "красным флагом" в коде. Именно потому, что вы все равно будете так или иначе перебирать все элементы. Если вы занимаетесь подобным двиганием итератора, не поддерживающего произвольный доступ (т.е. обычный оператор `+`), то возможно вы делаете что-то неправильно. В большинстве случаев вы должны относиться к такому применению `std::next`/`std::advance` как к временному "костылю" в коде.

Comment: к сожалению, очень часто, люди принебрегают использованием правильного(уместного) контейнера. ..

Answer (score 5):

Ну, по списку все равно придется идти по порядку...

Но в общем случае это делается примерно так:

```
auto iter = numbers.begin();
advance(it,N);
for (;iter != numbers.end(); iter++){
    ....
}
```

или

```
for (auto iter = next(numbers.begin(),N); iter != numbers.end(); iter++){
    ....
}
```

При этом, если контейнер позволяет переходить быстро - переход действительно будет быстрым...

Answer (score 2):

Пример инкремента итератора на 2 позиции.

```
std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin();
std::advance(it, 2);
```